# how to wrap inside <a href> all URL occurrence in my query

Tags: php, regex

alright, i think the solution to my question is to use REGEX, but my current knowledge of it hinders me to achieve the result that i want.

so basically, how do i make all `URL` occurrence in my posts/text entries to wrap inside an `<a href>` element when being queried.

when i `echo $content;` from a database it will display as:

```
this is a link http://somerandomsite.com, check it out!
```

but how can i make the link inside a text to be contained in `<a href>` tag when displayed.

id be honest to say that i dont know how to properly write the syntax. but this is what ive come up with.

```
//get url from content
$link = strstr($content, 'http://');

//insert <a href> for all $link inside $content
//then display $content with all links wrapped in <href>
```

Comment: Wasn't it: "I have a problem. I decided to do a regex to solve it. Now I have 2 problems."? Anyway: If you have no clue what the syntax should be, the most logical step would be to [find that out](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) first. Ask your question again after you have tried out regex using the documentation as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = 'this is a link http://somerandomsite.com, check it out!';

$a = preg_replace("/\b((?:http\:\/\/)|(?:www\.))([^ ,]+)/", "<a href=\"$1$2\">$1$2</a>", $a);

echo $a;
```